# trying to read the arguments for a jdbc programfrom an text file but getting an number format exception?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
package com.first;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public class Preparedtatementexm3 {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Connection con=null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    /*
     * 1.load the driver
     * driver class :com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

     */

    try {
        Driver driverref=new Driver();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driverref);
        /*
         * 2.get db connection via driver
         */
        String DbUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/college?    
                     user=suhas&password=j2ee";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(DbUrl);
        /*
         * 3.issue SQL queries via Connection
         */
        String query="insert into students_info values(?,?,?,?)";
        pstmt=con.prepareStatement(query);
        String fileloc="C:\\Users\\SUHAS B K GOWDA\\Desktop\\New Text  
                    Document (2).txt";  
        FileReader reader=new FileReader(fileloc);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(reader);
        String linedata=null;
        while((linedata=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] data=linedata.split(" ");
            pstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(data[0]));
            pstmt.setString(2,data[1]);
            pstmt.setString(3,data[2]);
            pstmt.setString(4, data[3]);
            int count=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("no of rows affected count "+count);
        }

        /*
         * 4.process the results returned by sql query
         */
        /*while(rs.next()){
            int dbregno=rs.getInt("regno");
            String fname=rs.getString("firstname");
            String mname=rs.getString("middlename");
            String lname=rs.getString("lastname");
            System.out.println("regno "+dbregno);
            System.out.println("first name "+fname );
            System.out.println("middlename "+mname);
            System.out.println("lastname "+lname);
            }//end of while
            */

    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        /*
         * close all jdbc objects
         */
        try {
            if(con!=null){
                con.close();

            }
            if(pstmt!=null){
                pstmt.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
    }
    }
```

even though its returning the output the exception is also being printed why so???
the console is showing
no of rows affected count 1
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.first.Preparedtatementexm3.main(Preparedtatementexm3.java:46)

Comment: Well, what does your file contain?

Comment: 16 mahendra singh dhoni
i have the above data in my file @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 0):

This `pstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(data[0]));`  line caused the exception.

The content of `data[0]` is not valid number. You better debug or print what value is present in `data[0]`.  Other possibility is `data[0]` may have space, in the case try `Integer.parseInt(data[0].trim())`.

Comment: well i tried Integer.parseInt(data[0].trim()). but the result doesn't change.@Prabhakaran

Comment: @user3079190 Please print the data[0] value. System.out.println(data[0]) and find what value is present.

Comment: it is printing the integer number which I have given in textfile.

Comment: @user3079190 Please update your question with your piece of input file.

Comment: the input file contains "16 mahendra singh dhoni " these four parameters.